# App crashes after refresh

Tags: reactjs, meteor, render

I have got a problem with my app. Everything is fine untill I press the refresh button. I assume it is happening because of some stuff is not ready to be rendered yet.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

import LeftNavbar from '../dashboard/LeftNavbar'
import UpperBar from '../dashboard/UpperBar'
import NewGreetingsForm from './NewGreetingsForm'
import ConfigureButtons from './ConfigureButtons'

import Fanpages from '../../../api/Fanpages.js'

import './Greetings.scss'

export class Greetings extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.fanpage = this.props.user.profile.fanpages

    this.state = {
      newGreetingsText: '',
      newGreetingsCharCount: 0
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
  }

  render () {
    const currentFanpage = Fanpages.findOne({fanpageName: this.fanpage})
    const currentGreeting = currentFanpage.fanpageInfo.fanpageInfo.config.greeting[0].text
    return (
      <div className='container page'>
        <UpperBar title={'Konfiguracja fanpage / Zdefiniuj greetings'} />
        <LeftNavbar />
        <div className='main-content'>
          <h4 id='main-title'>{this.fanpage}</h4>
          <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
              <ConfigureButtons />
              <div>
                <h5 id='configure-content-right'>Zmień obecną informację</h5>
                <NewGreetingsForm fanpageName={this.fanpage} placeholder={currentGreeting} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(createContainer(() => ({
  user: Meteor.user()
}), Greetings))
```

Any idea where I should move those variables from render method? So it works as it should after page refresh? Thanks a lot for any participation.

Comment: Can you provide some information about the error you are getting?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fanpageInfo' of undefined

Comment: It has to be related to subscription of MongoDB collection. I went through loads of resources on the internet however without result

Comment: Could you show the whole code of this component class, so the answer would be more specific.

Comment: I just updated the code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's subscription management going on above this component you can just defend against the data not being ready:

```
render () {
  const currentFanpage = Fanpages.findOne({fanpageName: this.fanpage});
  if (!currentFanpage) {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  } else {
    const currentGreeting = currentFanpage.fanpageInfo.config.greeting[0].text
    return (
      // your html
    )
  }
}
```

Better yet, have the parent component render a spinner until the subscription is `.ready()`

**Update**
You asked about using `createContainer` with `withRouter`. I don't normally use `withRouter` and I haven't tested this but it should go something like:

```
const container = () => {
  const sub = Meteor.subscribe('mysub');
  const loading = sub.ready();
  const user = Meteor.user();
  return { loading, user };
}

export default withRouter(container, Greetings))
```

The important thing being that the container have a `loading` key that's tied to the state of the subscription.

[Container tutorial](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-create-container)

Comment: I think using container would be better choice.

Comment: how to wait for the subscription? I saw few examples however non of them where with "withrouter"

Comment: Cheers buddy, your answer gave me a clue to sort it out. Appreciated